# xcode syntax question regarding @selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using CoreDateBooks and the Recipe samples as style guides, but also looking at many other samples and books.  Can someone help explain how to correctly write the @selector statement?  I see several different styles.

From CoreDataBooks, the add button selector is a single term with no colon, the method is an IBAction and it is declared in the interface.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addBook)];
...
- (IBAction)addBook {
}
```

From Recipes, the add button selector is a term followed by a colon, the method uses (void) and (id)sender, and it is not declared in the interface.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];
...
- (void)add:(id)sender {
```

Later in Recipes, the Cancel button has yet another syntax. The button selector is followed by a term with no colon, the method uses void but not sender, and again it is not declared in the interface.

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
...
- (void)cancel {
```

I understand that add and add: are different, with the second requiring a parameter, but is there a reason for one or the other?  And when would I need to place the method name in the interface?

In other words, when I declare my own selector, such as @selector(add) or @selector(cancel), can I simply use the -(void) format and not place it in the interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IBAction` is typedef'd to `void`. Its only function is to allow Interface Builder to map your interface elements to actions if your interface is in a nib file. It's declared in your interface file only so Interface Builder can see it. Thus there's no real difference between `- (IBAction)myAction` and `- (void)myAction`.

If your action method doesn't need to know what control/view triggered the action (i.e. it always does the same thing when the action is invoked on the target), you can omit the `(id)sender` parameter and pass in a selector without the colon.

If you're not using Interface Builder you don't have to use the `IBAction` format, and if your methods will only be invoked within the same class then there's no need to expose them in your header file (nor is there any harm in doing so).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to put the selector in the interface if you wish other classes (or Interface Builder) to use it.  Otherwise, just make sure the selector is defined in the .m file prior to using it.

Comment: ...intended to be in addition to what @BoltClock said.

Comment: Appreciate the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

1) For most delegate callback methods, if you provide a parameter-accepting callback the parameter will be the "sender", i.e. the source control.  You might need this parameter if you are using the same delegate method to handle the callbacks for multiple controls.  Or, if you want to affect some change on the source control in the callback, and you haven't otherwise stored a pointer to it.

2) The only time you MUST include the callback definition in the interface definition is if you want to hook up the callback using Interface Builder.  If you forget the implementation itself, the callback will likely crash the app as most controls that use callback-delegate methods dont first check to see that the method exists.

Comment: No delegates for the moment.  Trying to keep this simple.